# How can I create a full screen, borderless browser/ temporarily hide the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dom, browser

Is there be a way for me to view a web page in a borderless window, perhaps by manipulating the DOM?  Even if it were to only work in a specific browser, this would be fine.  Ideally, the window would be able to be closed, perhaps by mousing to the top of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most browsers, you can press F11 for full screen mode.

Comment: Thanks... Yeah, I was hoping to have the default state be borderless by default... I'll see if this is something I can set automatically via js for a particular browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [Pennywise Browser](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/pennywise). There's a few options to select like `View > Frameless Window` and `View > Toggle Navbar` but it does what you're requesting.